Rick durrett Stochastic process - Theorem 2.12
Following is a theorem statement in Rick Durrett's book on Stochastic processes.
Theorem 2.12. Suppose that in a Poisson process with rate A
, we keep a point that lands at s with probability p(s). Then the result is a non-homogenous Poisson process with rate A.p(s).
I have been struggling to prove this statement.
Seems,this theorem is quite powerful in analysis some difficult thinning problems.
Any hints will be helpful.
